# How does android's app screen resume a running activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle, android-launcher

I would like to know how the android app screen resumes a running activity or rather how the Intent used therefor looks like. I already tried to get the "resume-intent" by activity.getIntent() in the activity's onResume(), but it looks like that getIntent() only returns the "start-intent". So is there a way to get this "resume-intent" or does anybody know how it looks like?

Thx

Comment: Sorry, `onNewIntent()` is only for activities set for `singleTop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in a (now deleted) answer:

> I do following: Navigating to the activity -> pressing home button ->
>   click the according launcher-icon on the app screen (what brings me
>   back to my activity). The intent used in this case for resuming the
>   activity is what I'm interested in

There is no `Intent` sent to resume your `Activity` in this case. When you launch your application, Android just brings the existing task that contains your application from the background to the foreground and then resumes the `Activity` that is on the top of the stack.